# Very easy question. Please help

Tags: medicine

Very easy question for medical research. I have a group of 45 sick people of which 20 western and 25 non-western. My hypothesis states that there should be no difference between western and non-western to get the illness. How can I check this hypothesis? Can't be hard but I suck at statistics. Thx

Comment: More information is needed -- how many total Western and non-Western people were there? We also need to know how many did not get sick.

If 20 Western people got sick out of 100 and 25 non-Western people got sick out of 125, we won't see much of a difference. But if it's 20 out of 10,000 Western and 25 out of 100 non-Western, then we'd think it's very likely non-Western people are more likely to get the illness.

Comment: 1. Please use a title that conveys the nature of the question rather than your assessment of how difficult it might be. Please remove the same from the body, as well as  "I suck at statistics". Please also remove the thanks (these issues would go partway toward indicating why your question was downvoted). 2. What's left doesn't contain enough information to answer the question. If they get sick at the same rate but are not equally represented in the population, the raw numbers would differ.

Answer (score 3):

If that's all the data you have - that is, everyone in your data set has the illness - then there is no way to test your hypothesis. You would need data on a sample of people, some of whom have the illness and some don't and some of whom are western and some not.

Then you could do chi-square, which is quite simple, but it would probably be better to also collect data on features related to the illness (such as age or whatever) and do a logistic regression with "illness" as the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

To add two more options to @Peter Flom's answer:

If you do not want to collect data on features related to the illness, you may calculate odds ratio (OR). It will quantify the relationship. I mean, you can get information such as "Risk of disease for Western people is twice as large as for non-Western". This is could usefull, if there are differences between groups. Of course OR comes with p-value to see if relationship is significant.

If you don't want OR, and number of diseased or non-diseased people in your sample is small, Fisher's Exact test or G-test would be better than chi-squared test.

Comment: Risk ratio or relative risk is what you have described not the odds ratio.

Comment: You're right. I sholud write "*Odds* of disease for Western people is twice as large as for non-Western", then it would be OR. With  *Risk* or *Probability* is RR (relative risk, risk ratio).